# Set of linearly independent vectors in a tangent-space that spans a non-degenerate 2-plane are dense in the cartesian product of the tangent-space.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential, tangent-spaces

Let $R$ be the riemann curvature tensor, viewed as a $(0,4)$-tensor field. For $p \in M$, where we have a semi-riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, we can look at linearly independent vectors $u,v \in T_pM$ that spans a non-degenerate $2$-plane $\sigma$. According to notes from a course I am taking, the set $(u,v)$ of such pairs is dense in $T_pM \times T_pM$, and determines $R_p(u,v,v,u)$ by continuity. By "sets of such pairs", do they mean the set of *all* such pairs of vectors? That is, the set $$S := \{(u,v) \in T_pM \times T_pM: (u,v) \ \text{linearly independent and spans a 2-plane} \ \sigma\}.$$

Could someone point me to a proof of the statement about the set being dense, and why this determines $R_p(u,v,v,u)$ by continuity? The two note-sets I have does not prove this, but only mentions it.

Comment: Linearly independent for two vectors is equivalent to spanning a $2$-plane, so this condition is redundant in your definition

Comment: That is true. This was my professor:s formulation.

Comment: Do you have anything to add about the actual problem I raised?

Comment: If $u$ an $v$ are linearly dependent, take $w$ that is not proportional to them and consider $\{u,v+tw\}$ for $t\to 0$. This shows density of linearly independent pairs of vectors

Comment: By favorite way of showing that $R_p$ is determined by values of $R_p(u,v,v,u)$ is to notice from the symmetry of $R$ that $R_p$ is in fact a symmetric bilinear map on $\lambda^2 T_pM$ (by $B_p(u\wedge v,w\wedge t) = R_p(u,v,t,w)$), and by polarization, it is uniquely determined by the associated quadratic form $Q_p(u\wedge v) = B_p(u\wedge v,u\wedge v) = R_p(u,v,v,u)$.

Comment: On $\Lambda^2 T_pM$* not $\lambda^2$